# How do you pronounce GAMESS

Tags: quantum-chemistry

Do you pronounce the software's name, GAMESS, as ga-mess, gaim-z (as in plural of game) or something else.

I know it's sort of not the kind of question to ask here, but I couldn't think of anywhere else better.

Comment: *"Hello, this is L̶i̶n̶u̶s̶ ̶T̶o̶r̶v̶a̶l̶d̶s̶ Frank Neese, and I pronounce L̶i̶n̶u̶x̶ Gamess as ORCA."* To the topic, I more often hear people pronouncing GAMESS as [ɡeɪmz].

Comment: it's pronounced like the plural of game

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about chemistry.

Comment: Well, since the official GAMESS documentation doesn't insist on any particular pronunciation, I'd argue you can call it anyway you like. :D As mentioned by Jan Jensen the absolute majority of computational chemists indeed call it [ɡeɪmz], but I habitually call it something like [gɑːmɛs] and colleagues always understand what I'm talking about. :)

Comment: And I agree with @Mithoron: such question are better asked, say, in our chat than on the site.